# Ferramenta para zoom mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile com **Apache Cordova**, preciso de uma ferramenta semelhante ao [Zoomify](http://www.zoomify.com/), mas para mobile. Tentei utilizar o Zoomify, não obtive bons resultados, qual ferramenta é a mais adequada para este trabalho? Existe alguma API do Google Maps que faça este trabalho?

Comment: você quer dar zoom especificamente num map, ou em qualquer parte da sua aplicação mobile?

Comment: Vou ter imagens que vou dar o zoom nelas, igual ao Google Maps

Answer (score 1):

Veja se essa [essa](http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142?WT.ac=category_thumb&WT.seg_1=category_thumb&WT.z_author=VF&ref=ckome) serve. Mas é paga.
Exemplo:

```
$('#iddasuaimg').smoothZoom({
    width: <Enter Width>,
    height: <Enter Height>
});
```

[Demonstrações](http://vectorflower.com/preview/smooth_zoom/sample2.html)

Comment: Por mais que links ajudem com a resposta, é recomendável postar um exemplo, pois links podem deixar de ser funcionais, por mudança de endereço ou coisas do gênero.

Answer (score 1):

Em JQuery tem o [panzoom](http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/). [Aqui](http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/) tem um exemplo de como funciona.

Segundo a descrição no [Github](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/blob/master/README.md#loading-panzoom):

> Panzoom is a progressive plugin to create panning and zooming functionality for an element. Panzoom supports the same browsers as jQuery 2.0 and can be used with jQuery 1.9.0+ or jQuery 2.0+. Rather than setting width and height on an image tag, Panzoom uses CSS transforms and matrix functions to take advantage of hardware/GPU acceleration in the browser, which means the element can be anything: an image, a video, an iframe, a canvas, text, WHATEVER. And although IE<=8 is not supported, this plugin is future-proof.
>   [...]
>
> **Mobile support**
>   Panzoom includes support for touch gestures and even supports pinch gestures for zooming. It is perfectly suited for both mobile and desktop browsers. You'll be amazed at how well this performs on your mobile device.
>   iOS and Android are supported.
>   Pointer (IE11+), touch, and mouse events are supported.

As bibliotecas:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/jquery.panzoom.js"></script>
```

Inicialização:

```
$(".panzoom-elements").panzoom();

// Pass options
$("a.panzoom-elements").panzoom({
  minScale: 0,
  $zoomRange: $("input[type='range']")
});
```

O [link do repositório](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom) do Github.

Comment: Este não serve, perde a qualidade conforme o zoom.. Diferente do Zoomify

Comment: Já tentou esta http://e-smartdev.com/#!jsPluginList/panAndZoomJQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

Danilo, você tentou utilizar o plugin Cordova "Photo Viewer"?

Segue o link: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.speryans.photoviewer

Já trabalhei com Cordova, mas não precisei aplicar zoom nas imagens do meu app.

Vale a pena testar.

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o zoom na pagina Inteira é uma ideia diferente experimenta ai:

http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

Eu tenho ele em um sistema e precisei fazer alguns ajustes para rodar em todas os navegadores, então se for usar ele mesmo da um toque que passo os ajustes para fazer essa compatibilidade.